# Replacement for IndexReader.lastModified in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

In Lucene 4.7.1 the method `IndexReader.lastModified()` is already deleted (some time ago it was just deprecated). 
What is the current equivalent for `lastModified`?

Comment: check the javadoc of the given method: https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#lastModified(org.apache.lucene.store.Directory)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, if you are trying to determine whether the reader is current, or if it needs to be reopened, do *not* do the following with the commitData map.  Instead, simply use:  [`DirectoryReader.isCurrent()`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/DirectoryReader.html#isCurrent())

---

The deprecation notice in the 3.6 documentation provides a note that is still largely relevant (though not entirely up to date):

> If you need to track commit time of an index, you can store it in the commit data (see IndexWriter.commit(Map))

If you need to know the last commit time, you can store it in the UserData when committing, using [`IndexWriter.setCommitData`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#setCommitData(java.util.Map)):

```
Map<String, String> commitData = new HashMap();
commitData.put("lastModified", String.valueOf(new Date().getTime()));
indexWriter.setCommitData(commitData);
//Now commit...
```

And you can get the userdata from the IndexCommit from [`DirectoryReader.getIndexCommit()`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/DirectoryReader.html#getIndexCommit())

```
string modMillis = dirReader.getIndexCommit().getUserData().get("lastModified");
Date modDate = new Date(Long.valueOf(modifiedMillis));
```

**Note:** this will get the data for the `IndexCommit` that is currently opened by this reader.  As such, it is not useful for determining whether the index needs to be reopened.  Again, to do that, use `DirectoryReader.isCurrent()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I need.